# SQL: Or condition between parent and child fields

Tags: mysql, sql, one-to-many

In my front end application i have a unique search field for an entire table. 
I would like to know if there is a way in SQL to make an OR condition between two fields, one in the parent table and the second in the INNER JOIN (child) Table.

*Example*

Given the One To Many Relation
**User (ID, Name)** -> **Address (ID, Name, User_ID)**

I search with a string *S* and i want find every user that names *S* or every user that lives in a city named *S*

Comment: `select * from user where name='S' or id in(select id from Address where name='S')`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should suit your needs.

I have assumed that `Address.Name` is the field you want to be searching due to a lack of `Address.City`.

```
SELECT User.*
FROM User
JOIN Address ON Address.User_ID = User.ID
WHERE (User.Name LIKE '%S%' OR Address.Name LIKE '%S%');
```

This will give you the information for users who's name or city **contain** `S`. If you would prefer to search where they **start** with `S` then use the following:

```
SELECT User.*
FROM User
JOIN Address ON Address.User_ID = User.ID
WHERE (User.Name LIKE 'S%' OR Address.Name LIKE 'S%');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct user.*
from user
   join address on user.id = address.user_id
where user.name = 'S' or address.city = 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT * from USER user where user.name='S' or user.id IN(SELECT add.user_id from Address add where add.name='S')
```

Comment: This won't work. Your sub-query is returning address ID's and your IN statement is looking for user ID's. It may return rows but I highly doubt it will be correct.

Comment: IN statement is looking for User ids who lives in a city with "S" and if you go through the schema Address table contain User ids so no problem with that.

Comment: It's not the WHERE that is the problem. It's what you're selecting in your sub-query. `SELECT add.id from Address add where add.name='S'` will return a list of address ID's. `or user.id IN(ADDRESS_IDS_HERE)`. It should be `SELECT add.user_id`

Comment: Oh yes (I thought id was user_id). You got sharp eyes.